# Concurrent Selection of unique records

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I have read other strategies, but I wonder if there are any drawbacks to this strategy of selecting unique records concurrently.  In other words: If two threads run at the same time and attempt to select records at the same exact time, they will never select the same records.

Given table `TableName`, containing columns which include `ProcessID` which has a DEFAULT value of `NULL`.

***Edit for clarity***: `ProcessID` is not an Identity or Auto-Incremented field.  It may or may not be a FK to a Processes table, but that has yet to be decided.  It is an Identifier for code only at this point.

```
var myGUID = Guid.NewGuid();
ExecuteCommand("UPDATE TableName SET ProcessID = @myGUID WHERE ProcessID IS NULL", myGUID);
var myThreadsUniqueRecords = Query("SELECT * FROM TableName WHERE ProcessID = @myGUID", myGUID);
```

I stripped out code that would handle exceptions, rollbacks, and tracking if a ProcessID was previously updated, then orphaned.  I also realize there is a nearly impossible chance of a GUID collision, which I'd like to ignore unless significant reason to bring it up.

***The goal of the question is***: Is there any reason why this would ever return the same records to two different threads?  My understanding is that SQL Server will lock the selection and update of those records one process at a time, so there will never be a double update of a single record.

Comment: I don't think you will update the same record twice, but it's conceivable that you could assign the same processID to more than one record.

Comment: is there a reason why you don't want a number automatically generated by the server for you?

Comment: @Beth That's possible.  Are you suggesting an `output`?

Comment: no, in your table you can create an identity column that will generate the next number in sequence for you.

Comment: @Beth Right.  How would I then get those specific records, which were updated, back to my application?  At the moment my app knows the UUID, so it can query for it.  Is there a way for an Update to return the actual records?  Also, they wouldn't be allowed to be auto-gen Per-Record, the whole set would require the same UUID.

Comment: re: [getting the identity value back](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/retrieving-identity-or-autonumber-values)

Comment: re: if a set of rows uses the same ID, then you need a higher-level table with one row per set.  that's the table with the auto-generated ID column.

Comment: @Beth The ProcessID is not the Primary Key, Auto-Increment, or DB-Generated.  It is simply `NULL`, or the ID of the Process which owned/owns those records.  Either way, while I always like alternatives as food for thought, my main question is that, with the example provided (or perhaps with very slight tweaks), would the same records ever be returned to two concurrent threads?

Comment: Is there any chance of the transaction being used here getting rolled back at some point, rather than being committed?

Comment: As far as I know, this strategy is fine, I used it several times (not with guids, and usually with UPDATE TOP(x) or similar, but that is not relevant here). If you are doing this to kind of split workload over multiple workers - better add one more column indicating when worker has taken this item, because worker can crash and leave your items with "ProcessID" set without any chance for them to be taken by others.

Comment: Thanks @Evk.  That's what I meant by "tracking if a ProcessID was previously updated, then orphaned."  There's a small subsystem for tracking that issue.

Comment: By the way, you can use "update ... output" statement to update and select in one statement. Then you will not need uuids also, because any type can be used (like boolean IsProcessing, or number of your worker).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While your approach is safe, I'd suggest slightly different approach. First, you don't need to update then select separately, instead use OUTPUT statement:

```
UPDATE TableName 
    SET ProcessID = @myGUID
    OUTPUT INSERTED.*
    WHERE ProcessID IS NULL
```

This will update and select affected rows in single statement.

With that statement in mind - you don't actually need to use any guids. You can use even boolean field indicating if current item is currently being processed:

```
UPDATE TableName 
    SET IsProcessing = true
    OUTPUT INSERTED.*
    WHERE IsProcessing = false
```

And it will be as safe as with using guids, because two transaction will not be able to update the same row at the same time. You might want to add column indicating when item started being processed and introduce a timeout to handle situation when your worker crashes. Also, you might want to not take all rows in the table at the same time - UPDATE TOP (x) helps with that:

```
UPDATE TOP (10) TableName
    SET IsProcessing = true, ProcessingStarted = SYSUTCDATETIME()
    OUTPUT INSERTED.*
    WHERE IsProcessed = false AND 
    (IsProcessing = false OR DATEDIFF(minute, ProcessingStarted, SYSUTCDATETIME()) > 60)
```

Comment: Like you mention with doing the Update and Select in one step, I was also doing the other things in multiple steps too.  That is a great way to do all of those steps in one go.